# Trying to make a constantly running line graph

Tags: java, linegraph

I have a program that is operating fine which repeats a series of formulas using different values for independent variables. I now want to make a plot of the calculations after every iteration of the loop. This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    JFrame window=new JFrame();
    window.setTitle("Try");
    window.setSize(600, 400);
    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);

    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("graph");
    XYSeriesCollection dataset= new XYSeriesCollection(series);

    ...
```

My big questions are how do I take my data and generate a dataset, and then how do I make the graph update after every iteration of the loop? I have imported the JFreeChart class and some swing. Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out after some time. The trick is to set visible inside of the loop. But now, the JFrame redraws with every iteration. I don't know if there is a way to hold the frame constant. If anyone does know, I would appreciate the help.

```
package trylog{
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
java.util.List;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CombinedDomainXYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.Dataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.DatasetChangeListener;
import org.jfree.data.general.DatasetGroup;
import org.jfree.data.time.Millisecond;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
import sun.security.jca.GetInstance.Instance;

public class TryLog {
private static Object InstanceTools;
public static void main(String[] args) {


    JFrame window=new JFrame();
    window.setTitle("Try");
    window.setSize(600, 400);
    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //window.setVisible(true);

    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("graph");
    XYSeriesCollection dataset= new XYSeriesCollection(series);
    double[] newArray= new double[1000];
    for (int j=0;j<1000;j++)
    {
        newArray[j]=1+10;
    }
    JFreeChart chart=ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Graph Try", "hi", "bye", dataset);
    window.add(new ChartPanel(chart),BorderLayout.CENTER);

    int x=0;
    int number=10;

  JFrame window1=new JFrame();
    window1.setTitle("Try");
    window1.setSize(600, 400);
    window1.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    window1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //window.setVisible(true);

    XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("graph");
    XYSeriesCollection dataset1= new XYSeriesCollection(series1);

    double[] newArray1= new double[1000];
    for (int j=0;j<1000;j++)
    {
        newArray[j]=1+10;
    }
    JFreeChart chart1=ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Graph Try", "hi", "bye", dataset1);
    window1.add(new ChartPanel(chart1),BorderLayout.CENTER);

    int y=0;
    int number1=10;
    for (int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
       series.add(x,number);
        x++;
        number++;

        window.setVisible(true);


        series1.add(y,number1);
        y++;
        number1++;
        window1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```